# BxSlider and bootstrap collapsible element issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bxslider

I have been trying to put a bootstrap collapsible element inside a bxslider slide but it's not working at all.

Any ideas how to fix this?

I have uploaded sample code on my site:

http://www.nicksotiriadis.gr/test-folder/temp-bx.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code, it looks like bxSlider is doing a .clone of the elements for the slider without their data and events. If this is the case, the collapse isn't working because the Bootstrap event handler is not on the cloned elements.

The best approach might be to use the "onSliderLoad" event to call the collapse from Bootstrap directly.

Example **(updated)**:

```
$(function () {
    var sideslider = $('#sideslider').bxSlider({
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        touchEnabled: false,
        pager: false,
        slideWidth: 270,
        onSliderLoad: function () {
            $('.bx-viewport').on('click','a.collapse-toggle', function () {
                //var ele = $(this).parent().find('.collapse-box'); // element to to collapse (UL)
                //ele.collapse('toggle');
                $(this).parent().find('.collapse-box').collapse('toggle');    // one liner
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** I looked at it a little more and realized by old example using the ID was a bad idea because of the cloning I pointed out. *doh*

Here's the markup created: http://screencast.com/t/yRnW1zUA

You can't reuse IDs since they are unique per item per page via spec. While clicking the DROP button would cause it to work, you can't witness it because it's happening on the first element matching the ID. And that is normally hidden with the slide.

Video for example: http://screencast.com/t/AI0Ex2GIsP - Watch the left for the yellow highlights. Those are the changes occurring and note they are not the element you see.

While looking at that, though, I also realized there was another issue I had run into previously trying to use the Bootstrap collapse - If you trigger via JS, don't use the Bootstrap classes and data-toggle attributes because they will conflict.

After that was said, the end result is removing the Bootstrap data-toggle attributes and classes, putting your own in, and referencing the element in that slide. It's much simpler than it sounds. And because you have the sideslider already there, you might be able to bind "click" to that using "on" without using the onSliderLoad event.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yJTJf/2/

Comment: ..although I only understood half of what you said, let me check this and get back to you. How did you manage to extract this information? What tool are you using?

Comment: For the clone, I looked at the BXSlider JS file to see what it is doing. Then I looked at the source of your code for the rest :) FireBug in FireFox or Web Developer Tools in Chrome will give you a good console to see errors. Looking at it now, I can fully see that because the markup is using IDs for referencing the items, and the slides are being cloned, as I pointed out, you have multiple elements with the same ID. It's working, but you can't see it because it't working on the first item matching that ID.

Comment: I'll update with a newer sample in a few minutes to hopefully demonstrate what's happening.

Comment: I already Did update. The latest version is above. Have a read and test and let me know.

Comment: I see your point! thanks for getting into all this trouble to explain what happened! I will also try too look if there's a possibility for the slider NOT to create multiple elements or use classes and get back to you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason I am posting a new answer is because Daved was kind enough to explain what causes the problem so I looked into it a bit more, here is my conclusion.

Bxslider has an infiniteLoop option , which, if set to false, doesn't create any clones of the slides, so the IDS stay unique.

Now the collapses SEEM not to open, only because bxslides don't have dynamic height (different than adaptiveHeight which reads the slide's height BEFORE it's brought into the scren). If you add some content below the slide you'll see that the collapsible actually works.

For the second slide in my example, when you first click on it, it opens, and then if you go to the previous slide and then back to it adaptiveHeight adjust so that it shows.

So, only thing that is needed now is dynamic slide height - I have already issued a request on gitHub, I hope it gets heard - it is very useful and I am certain others will use it as well.

Updated my example with the code above:

http://www.nicksotiriadis.gr/test-folder/temp-bx.html